# apps-script: race condition when loading spreadsheet, giving incorrect data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I've got an interesting problem on an apps script web app. On startup, and in the handlers, the code gets a small range of data (about 20 values) from spreadsheet A, with `getRangeByName`. Spreadsheet A is not complex, but it has 4 pages, and two of the pages are loaded up from Spreadsheet B (using `importRange`). Each of these two pages is loaded up with a single `ImportRange`, pulling in about 6000 cells each.

Here's the problem. When the user clicks on the web app URL, a lot of the time (maybe 25% of attempts) the data loaded by `getRangeByName` is incorrect. The returned data is `#VALUE!` instead of the actual spreadsheet data. The actual data that should have been returned is text (a person's name) which is derived from the linked (`importRange`) spreadsheet.

This normally happens on startup (in `doGet`), but I've also seen this on one occasion after the user clicks a button.

It looks very much like `getRangeByName` is returning before the spreadsheet has finished loading data via `importRange`. This is not really a major problem - I've just changed the script so that it loops on `getRangeByName`, with a `sleep`, until a given cell has the known correct value. The fix seems to work, after limited testing. However, this does seem pretty amateurish. Has anyone else seen this? Is this a known issue, and is there a 'proper' way to handle this?

**FIRST EDIT**

The sleep/re-read fix didn't work, and I added the code below. I call this instead of a plain `openById` to open the spreadsheet. This code originally included only the second `flush` call. This code still fails occasionally, with the *second* throw, even though this appears to be impossible. What's happening here is that GAS (eventually) manages to get the correct spreadsheet data inside the for loop, it then exits the for loop and tries to fetch exactly the same data, and the data is now *incorrect*.

**SECOND EDIT**

I've added a second flush operation to the code below, which is before the first call to `getRangeByName`, as suggested in the comments. No difference; the code failed (again with the *second* throw) on the third call to `InputSpreadsheetOpen` (in a handler).

```
/**
 * Work around what appears to be a Google race condition when opening
 * the input spreadsheet. If we can't read what we expect from a range
 * in the spreadsheet, just sleep and try again.
 */
function InputSpreadsheetOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(INPUT_SS);
  var data;

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();         // should be completely pointless...
  for(var i=0; ; i++) {
    data = ss.getRangeByName("swimmerNames").getValues();
    if(data == null)
      throw(" 'swimmerNames' is not defined."); // spreadsheet error
    if(data[0] == FIRST_NAME)
      break;                                    // got expected value
    if(i <10) {                                 // Google error?
      Utilities.sleep(500);                     // ms; total 5s
      continue;
    } else
      throw("The server appears to be busy. Please refresh the browser page.");
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();         // should be completely pointless...
  data = ss.getRangeByName("swimmerNames").getValues();
  if(data[0] != FIRST_NAME)
    throw("GAS is broken. Reload and pray.");
  return ss;
} // InputSpreadsheetOpen()
```

Comment: Have you tried SpreadsheetApp.flush() before getRangeByName?

Comment: If flush doesn't work, you can load the data directly from Spreadsheet B in the script as well.

Comment: Added the flush (see above), though it does seem pointless when opening a spreadsheet. I can't read Spreadsheet B directly in the script - it's required by spreadsheet A, and the script requires the output of spreadsheet A, not the contents of B.

Comment: Have you tried SpreadsheetApp.flush() before getRangeByName? The operative word is 'before'.

Comment: It's before the second getRangeByName. If it was going to work, surely that would be sufficient? It's the second call that fails, eventually. I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: Ok, just tried it - I've duplicated the flush line exactly just above the 'for' statement, ie. before the first getRangeByName. It failed on the third spreadsheet read (not in doGet, but in a handler), again displaying the 'reload' (ie. *second*) failure message.